# Specify organization unit using aws cloudformation create-stack-instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-organizations

I am trying to add instances to a StackSet by specifying the ou.  This is possible using the console, but can't seem to find a way to do this using the cli.  When i use an ou code I get an error:

```
aws cloudformation create-stack-instances --stack-set-name test-stack --accounts "ou-1234-asdfsfsdf" --regions '["eu-west-1"]' --operation-preferences FailureToleranceCount=0,MaxConcurrentCount=1
```

`An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStackInstances operation: 1 validation error detected: Value '[ou-1234-asdfsfsdf]' at 'accounts' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy constraint: [Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [0-9]{12}]`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--deployment-targets OrganizationalUnitIds=string` structure instead of specifying OU in accounts

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/create-stack-instances.html